# IE 6 & IE 7 printing radio buttons

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing, radio-button

I have a "calculator" which has two radio buttons ([link to form](http://ads-pipe.com/en/resources/calc_ag_drainageknownSize.asp)) you select before you perform the calculation. 
To see my issue, you select the radio button marked "N-12" [to test, we just put "5" in "Slope" and "30" in "Pipe Size" and select "N-12", then calculate], then perform the calculation everything is fine until you print.
Because people want to have a paper copy of the calculation, they often print the calculated form after it's completed but if you've selected "N-12" and printed the page, it will print with the "Single Wall" radio button selected.
I've read that this is a bug and that you can force IE8 to recognize the checked radio button with JS, which is what I did, but it's not working for IE6 & 7.
This is the JS that I used to correct this problem for IE8:

```
function toggleRadioCheckbox(el) {
if ( el.getAttribute('checked') != 'checked' ) {
    el.setAttribute('checked','checked');
}
else {
    el.removeAttribute("checked");
}
```

}

Does anyone know what I need to do to correct this for IE6 and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Try this (requires jQuery) solution:

```
// We want the change event to trigger when the radio buttons are clicked.
// Normally IE doesn't
// trigger change until the radio button has lost focus.  
// Fake it with this click handler
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    this.blur();
    this.focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, I'll give that at try soon!

Comment: I added that to my page, but when you go to print from IE6 or IE7, they reset the radio buttons just before it prints, so valiant effort, but that didn't do it.

Comment: I just went to the link in your original post.  I'm using Win 7 Enterprise and IE 8.  I filled in the form, chose the "N-12" radio button, clicked "Calculate".  The calculated values appeared.  I then printed the page, once to a real printer and once to the Adobe PDF "printer".  In both cases, the radio button is in the "N-12" state.  Maybe try clearing your browser cache and retrying to print?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Sorry it took a while to test, we just got hit by another massive snow storm.